# Batch file for check database integrity sql server

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am trying to get a batch file to help me get the list of database from each instance, and I will run the following query against each database to check the database integrity.

```
    DBCC CHECKDB(N'database name')  WITH NO_INFOMSGS
    GO
```

I am very unfamiliar with batch file language, anyone could help me with that?

Comment: This will probably require dynamic-sql and so on. Better use [Maintenance Plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002.aspx) and `Define Database Check Integrity (CHECKDB) Tasks`

Comment: I know that the Maintenance plan or agent job will be easier for me but it is kind of company system standard.